# Cassandra INSERT SELECT query

Tags: cassandra, cql

How can I convert this SQL query that enable to transfer some data from a table to another to a CQL query ?

`INSERT INTO foo.table1 SELECT column_id, column2 FROM foo.table2 WHERE column_id >= ? AND column_id < ?`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select data from a table and insert into another table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21363046/how-to-select-data-from-a-table-and-insert-into-another-table)

Comment: @AleksandarStojadinovic Is it possible to duplicate the data without using a temp file ?

Comment: To be honest, I haven't tried that. Do you mean duplicating it on insert?

Comment: @AleksandarStojadinovic Yes

Comment: Maybe you should consider changing your insert query or something like that, so you can at least leave it to the dbms to work out. Can you change you applications data access layer?