# Cassandra: Push the filtered rows to a new column family using CQL and delete them from existing column family

Tags: cassandra, cql

I'm a newbie to cassandra. I have a confusion with archival of data. Following is the approach I am trying to implement.

- Filter the records to be archived.
- Create a new column family
- Move the filtered records to the new column family
- Delete the filtered records from existing column family

**Filter the records to be archived.** - Achieved with the use of secondary indexes
**Create a new column family** Create Query
**Move the filtered records to the new column family** I thought of implementing this by the approach mentioned in [cassandra copy data from one columnfamily to another columnfamily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17542239/cassandra-copy-data-from-one-columnfamily-to-another-columnfamily) 
 But this copies all the data from column family 1 to 2. Is it possible to move only the filtered rows to new column family?
**Delete the filtered records from existing column family** I am not sure of how to achieve this in CQL. Please help me.

Additionally, Let me know if there is any better approach.

Answer (score 0):

COPY then DELETE sounds like a valid strategy here.

For deleting rows, take a look at the [DELETE](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/delete_r.html) command, it takes the same WHERE condition as a SELECT does.

Unfortunately this [won't work for a query that requires "ALLOW FILTERING"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18515874/cassandra-delete-by-secondary-index-or-by-allowing-filtering), although there is an [enhancement request](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-5527) to add this.

Comment: I am not sure of deleting only the filtered rows from existing Column family. 
My select query is something like
select * from sample where name='abc' and score>=50 and score<=100 limit 1000 allow filtering; 
I am not sure of applying this in delete.

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work for a query that requires "ALLOW FILTERING" according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18515874/cassandra-delete-by-secondary-index-or-by-allowing-filtering, although there is an enhancement request to add this at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-5527